# Subversion svn:global_ignores not working completely

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Something very strange.

In my ubuntu server with subversion 1.8, I do

```
svnadmin create /var/svn/workspace-test
svn checkout file:///var/svn/workspace-test /var/svn/workspace-test/tmp 
cd /var/svn/workspace-test/tmp
svn propset -R svn:global-ignores -F .svnignore .
svn commit --non-interactive -m "" .
rm -R svn commit --non-interactive -m "" .
```

My `.svnignore`

```
*.o
*.lo
*.la
*.al
.libs
*.so
*.so.[0-9]*
*.a
*.pyc
*.pyo
*.rej
*~
#*#
.#*
.*.swp
.DS_Store
*.classpath
*.project
.settings
target
.metadata
RemoteSystemsTempFiles
bin
.buildpath
```

Now on windows with tortoisesvn I do a check out for `workspace-test`.

In `workspace-test` I create that structure

```
workspace-test
|- test1
   |- target
|- test2
   |- toto
   |- target
|- test3
   |- src
   |- target
```

And when do a commit, torsoisesvn gives me in the changes list

```
test1
test2
test2/toto
test3
test3/src
test3/target
```

So it seems the `target` folder is not ignored if there is a `src` folder

--Edit--

Same structure and command line under ubuntutu

```
svn add --force *
svn commit -m "..."
```

and it's good.

Ans using same commands under dos (so tortoise client), it's also working !

Comment: If a directory or file is already in the repository, it won't be ignored. Also, `svn:global-ignores` only works in SVN 1.8.

Comment: I'm using svn 1.8.  And at this stage there is nothing in the repository.  target is ignored if it is with toto and not if it is with src !

Comment: Ok, it seems to be a tortoise svn problem.  See edited answer.